# Traversal of cities - is this case missing from the solution?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

*Warning: this question requires some initial effort to be understood*

This question is not exactly a duplicate of [dynamic programming : traversal of cities](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13435023). Let's suppose I have the following graph for 4 cities [0-3]:

```
  d[0][1] = 1;
  d[0][2] = 2;
  d[0][3] = 5;
  d[1][2] = 3;
  d[1][3] = 6;
  d[2][3] = 4;
```

The solution proposed in the link is

```
C[i,j] = {
   C[i,j-1] + d[j-1,j]                   (if i < j-1)
   min C[k,i] + d[k,j] for 0 <= k < i    (if i = j-1)
}
```

but let's calculate c[1][2]:

```
c[1][2] = min between {
           k = 0 => C[0,1] + d[0][2]
          }
```

This makes sense but **it is not the only path to evaluate** at this step, since I could have grouped cities [0,1] into the first set and had [2] alone for the second set. In that case it would have been

```
c[1][2] = min between {
           k = 0 => C[0,1] + d[0][2]
           d[0][1]
          }
```

At this point I'd like to ask if my objection makes sense at all. In case it did and the algorithm proposed in the link above was wrong, how should I include this occurrence in the solution? I tried to formulate it recursively but couldn't come up with anything simple.

Answer (score 0):

The solution you are referring to is indeed incomplete and does not account for the case when the second traveler starts at `j`. To account for that, update the recurrent relation to:

```
C[i,j] = {
   C[i,j-1] + d[j-1,j]                   (if i < j-1)
   min C[k,i] + d[k,j] for 0 <= k < i
       and C[0,i]                        (if i = j-1)
}
```

Here the exception would be `C[0,1]` which should be set to `d[0,1]`

This way you also account for the case when the second traveler just started (`C[0,i]` will be the cost of the first traveler traveling from 0 to `i`, and there's no cost for the second traveler to start at `j = i+1`).

Note that you can also replace `0 <= k < i` with `0 < k < i`, because `k = 0` results in `C[0,i] + d[0,j]` which is strictly greater than `C[0,i]`

Comment: ` k = 0 => C[0,1] + d[0][2]` is the right one, sorry that was a typo. But the question remains: In `C[0,1] it is assumed that one ends in 0 and one ends in 1. What if one goes from 0 to 1 and the other **starts and remains** in 2? The text says `Assume that person A and person B start initially at the first city in their respective subsequences`, they can start both at 0 but they can also **not** start in the same city

Comment: Yes, I misread the problem statement, I thought they have to start at `0`. Then you are right, the solution proposed there is not accounting for the case that one of the travelers can start in the `j`. I will update my answer in a second.

Comment: I updated the answer again. My previous update was incorrect, so if you started reading it, make sure to refresh the answer.